# .aspx page - using document.getElementById in pageLoad()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In writing a .net web application using AJax, should I *always* use global variables to store controls within the pageLoad() function?

**Example -**

```
  var x;
  var y;

  function pageLoad() {

            x = document.getElementById("<%= cboX.ClientID %>");
            y = document.getElementById("<%= tbxY.ClientID %>");  
  }

  function doStuff1() {

            x.enabled = false;
            y.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
```

**Or in some cases should I do this -**

```
    function doStuff2() {

            document.getElementById("<%= cboX.ClientID %>").enabled = false;
            document.getElementById("<%= tbxY.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid globals and do this:

```
function doStuff2() {
    document.getElementById("<%= cboX.ClientID %>").enabled = false;
    document.getElementById("<%= tbxY.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Gabe. Is there a reason why to avoid globals?

Comment: There are many reasons to avoid globals unless absolutely necessary. One major issue could be concurrency. The fact that the entire application could change the value inadvertently without realizing it causing a large headache for you. So long story short if you don't need them, such as this case, don't use them.

Comment: Thanks again Gabe. A couple of contributers seem to disagree with you. But you are getting more votes.

Comment: @ABogus, no problem. Clearly you don't need globals here and it's bad practice to use them especially when unnecessary. Be sure to mark it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Just remember that there is a cost to getElementById each time it is called, while this isn't a huge factor with modern browsers this can be a problem with IE, especially older versions. Also if the variables change in the code behind you'll need to manually do a search and replace for all instances in javascript strings.

Answer (score 2):

I would create one global object that has properties for each of your controls.

The problem with this approach in every function:

```
function doStuff2() {
    document.getElementById("<%= cboX.ClientID %>").enabled = false;
    document.getElementById("<%= tbxY.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Is that you can't refactor the JavaScript automatically when you rename your controls in the code behind.

If you do this:

```
var Controls = {};

function pageLoad() {

        Controls.x = document.getElementById("<%= cboX.ClientID %>");
        Controls.y = document.getElementById("<%= tbxY.ClientID %>");  
}

function doStuff1() {

        Controls.x.enabled = false;
        Controls.y.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Then you only ever have one place when your are referencing the client ID in the string.

Comment: Thanks dmck! But now I have two answers that seem to be conflicting. dmck's and Gabe's. Any one else want to be the tie breaker? :)

Comment: @ABogus there is no definitive "right" answer, while it's a good idea to keep globals to a minimum (which is done by keeping them in one `controls` var) you should also consider if you want to have ASPX tags throughout your javascript or if you want them in a central location.